# Can you add new statements to Python's syntax?

Tags: python, syntax, language-specifications

Can you add new statements (like `print`, `raise`, `with`) to Python's syntax?

Say, to allow..

```
mystatement "Something"
```

Or,

```
new_if True:
    print "example"
```

Not so much if you *should*, but rather if it's possible (short of modifying the python interpreters code)

Comment: On a somewhat related note, one use-case where it could be handy to create new statements on the fly (as opposed to seriously "extending" the language) is for people who use the interactive interpreter as a calculator, or even an OS shell.  I often create little throwaway functions on the fly to do something I'm going to repeat, and in those situations would be nice to create very abbreviated commands like macros or statements rather than typing the long names with function() syntax.  Of course that's not really what Py is for.. but people do spend a lot of time using it interactively.

Comment: @Kilo it might be worth looking at ipython - it has a lot of shell'ish features, for example you can use regular "ls" and "cd" commands, tab-completion, lots of macro-ish features etc

Comment: Some languages are exquisitely extensible, e.g. Forth and Smalltalk, but their language paradigms are different than that used by Python as well. With both of those any new words (Forth) or methods (Smalltalk) become an integral, indistiguishable part of the language for that installation. So each Forth or Smalltalk installation becomes a unique creation over time. Also Forth is RPN based. But thinking along the lines of DSLs, something like this should be accomplishable in Python. Though, as others have said here, why?

Comment: As someone fluent in both Python and Forth, and who has implemented several Forth compilers in years past, I can contribute here with some degree of authority.

Without gaining raw access to the internal parser of Python, it's completely impossible.  You can fake it by preprocessing, as the (frankly, rather slick!) answers below illustrate, but truly updating the syntax and/or semantics of the language in a hot interpreter is not possible.  This is both Python's curse as well as its advantage over Lisp- and Forth-like languages.

Answer (score 196, accepted):

You may find this useful - [Python internals: adding a new statement to Python](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/06/30/python-internals-adding-a-new-statement-to-python/), quoted here:

---

This article is an attempt to better understand how the front-end of Python works. Just reading documentation and source code may be a bit boring, so I'm taking a hands-on approach here: I'm going to add an `until` statement to Python.

All the coding for this article was done against the cutting-edge Py3k branch in the [Python Mercurial repository mirror](http://code.python.org/hg/branches/py3k/).

#### The `until` statement

Some languages, like Ruby, have an `until` statement, which is the complement to `while` (`until num == 0` is equivalent to `while num != 0`). In Ruby, I can write:

```
num = 3
until num == 0 do
  puts num
  num -= 1
end
```

And it will print:

```
3
2
1
```

So, I want to add a similar capability to Python. That is, being able to write:

```
num = 3
until num == 0:
  print(num)
  num -= 1
```

#### A language-advocacy digression

This article doesn't attempt to suggest the addition of an `until` statement to Python. Although I think such a statement would make some code clearer, and this article displays how easy it is to add, I completely respect Python's philosophy of minimalism. All I'm trying to do here, really, is gain some insight into the inner workings of Python.

#### Modifying the grammar

Python uses a custom parser generator named `pgen`. This is a LL(1) parser that converts Python source code into a parse tree. The input to the parser generator is the file `Grammar/Grammar`**[1]**. This is a simple text file that specifies the grammar of Python.

**[1]**: From here on, references to files in the Python source are given relatively to the root of the source tree, which is the directory where you run configure and make to build Python.

Two modifications have to be made to the grammar file. The first is to add a definition for the `until` statement. I found where the `while` statement was defined (`while_stmt`), and added `until_stmt` below **[2]**:

```
compound_stmt: if_stmt | while_stmt | until_stmt | for_stmt | try_stmt | with_stmt | funcdef | classdef | decorated
if_stmt: 'if' test ':' suite ('elif' test ':' suite)* ['else' ':' suite]
while_stmt: 'while' test ':' suite ['else' ':' suite]
until_stmt: 'until' test ':' suite
```

**[2]**: This demonstrates a common technique I use when modifying source code I’m not familiar with: *work by similarity*. This principle won’t solve all your problems, but it can definitely ease the process. Since everything that has to be done for `while` also has to be done for `until`, it serves as a pretty good guideline.

Note that I've decided to exclude the `else` clause from my definition of `until`, just to make it a little bit different (and because frankly I dislike the `else` clause of loops and don't think it fits well with the Zen of Python).

The second change is to modify the rule for `compound_stmt` to include `until_stmt`, as you can see in the snippet above. It's right after `while_stmt`, again.

When you run `make` after modifying `Grammar/Grammar`, notice that the `pgen` program is run to re-generate `Include/graminit.h` and `Python/graminit.c`, and then several files get re-compiled.

#### Modifying the AST generation code

After the Python parser has created a parse tree, this tree is converted into an AST, since ASTs are [much simpler to work with](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/02/16/abstract-vs-concrete-syntax-trees/) in subsequent stages of the compilation process.

So, we're going to visit `Parser/Python.asdl` which defines the structure of Python's ASTs and add an AST node for our new `until` statement, again right below the `while`:

```
| While(expr test, stmt* body, stmt* orelse)
| Until(expr test, stmt* body)
```

If you now run `make`, notice that before compiling a bunch of files, `Parser/asdl_c.py` is run to generate C code from the AST definition file. This (like `Grammar/Grammar`) is another example of the Python source-code using a mini-language (in other words, a DSL) to simplify programming. Also note that since `Parser/asdl_c.py` is a Python script, this is a kind of [bootstrapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_%28compilers%29) - to build Python from scratch, Python already has to be available.

While `Parser/asdl_c.py` generated the code to manage our newly defined AST node (into the files `Include/Python-ast.h` and `Python/Python-ast.c`), we still have to write the code that converts a relevant parse-tree node into it by hand. This is done in the file `Python/ast.c`. There, a function named `ast_for_stmt` converts parse tree nodes for statements into AST nodes. Again, guided by our old friend `while`, we jump right into the big `switch` for handling compound statements and add a clause for `until_stmt`:

```
case while_stmt:
    return ast_for_while_stmt(c, ch);
case until_stmt:
    return ast_for_until_stmt(c, ch);
```

Now we should implement `ast_for_until_stmt`. Here it is:

```
static stmt_ty
ast_for_until_stmt(struct compiling *c, const node *n)
{
    /* until_stmt: 'until' test ':' suite */
    REQ(n, until_stmt);

    if (NCH(n) == 4) {
        expr_ty expression;
        asdl_seq *suite_seq;

        expression = ast_for_expr(c, CHILD(n, 1));
        if (!expression)
            return NULL;
        suite_seq = ast_for_suite(c, CHILD(n, 3));
        if (!suite_seq)
            return NULL;
        return Until(expression, suite_seq, LINENO(n), n->n_col_offset, c->c_arena);
    }

    PyErr_Format(PyExc_SystemError,
                 "wrong number of tokens for 'until' statement: %d",
                 NCH(n));
    return NULL;
}
```

Again, this was coded while closely looking at the equivalent `ast_for_while_stmt`, with the difference that for `until` I've decided not to support the `else` clause. As expected, the AST is created recursively, using other AST creating functions like `ast_for_expr` for the condition expression and `ast_for_suite` for the body of the `until` statement. Finally, a new node named `Until` is returned.

Note that we access the parse-tree node `n` using some macros like `NCH` and `CHILD`. These are worth understanding - their code is in `Include/node.h`.

#### Digression: AST composition

I chose to create a new type of AST for the `until` statement, but actually this isn't necessary. I could've saved some work and implemented the new functionality using composition of existing AST nodes, since:

```
until condition:
   # do stuff
```

Is functionally equivalent to:

```
while not condition:
  # do stuff
```

Instead of creating the `Until` node in `ast_for_until_stmt`, I could have created a `Not` node with an `While` node as a child. Since the AST compiler already knows how to handle these nodes, the next steps of the process could be skipped.

#### Compiling ASTs into bytecode

The next step is compiling the AST into Python bytecode. The compilation has an intermediate result which is a CFG (Control Flow Graph), but since the same code handles it I will ignore this detail for now and leave it for another article.

The code we will look at next is `Python/compile.c`. Following the lead of `while`, we find the function `compiler_visit_stmt`, which is responsible for compiling statements into bytecode. We add a clause for `Until`:

```
case While_kind:
    return compiler_while(c, s);
case Until_kind:
    return compiler_until(c, s);
```

If you wonder what `Until_kind` is, it's a constant (actually a value of the `_stmt_kind` enumeration) automatically generated from the AST definition file into `Include/Python-ast.h`. Anyway, we call `compiler_until` which, of course, still doesn't exist. I'll get to it an a moment.

If you're curious like me, you'll notice that `compiler_visit_stmt` is peculiar. No amount of `grep`-ping the source tree reveals where it is called. When this is the case, only one option remains - C macro-fu. Indeed, a short investigation leads us to the `VISIT` macro defined in `Python/compile.c`:

```
#define VISIT(C, TYPE, V) {\
    if (!compiler_visit_ ## TYPE((C), (V))) \
        return 0; \
```

It's used to invoke `compiler_visit_stmt` in `compiler_body`. Back to our business, however...

As promised, here's `compiler_until`:

```
static int
compiler_until(struct compiler *c, stmt_ty s)
{
    basicblock *loop, *end, *anchor = NULL;
    int constant = expr_constant(s->v.Until.test);

    if (constant == 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    loop = compiler_new_block(c);
    end = compiler_new_block(c);
    if (constant == -1) {
        anchor = compiler_new_block(c);
        if (anchor == NULL)
            return 0;
    }
    if (loop == NULL || end == NULL)
        return 0;

    ADDOP_JREL(c, SETUP_LOOP, end);
    compiler_use_next_block(c, loop);
    if (!compiler_push_fblock(c, LOOP, loop))
        return 0;
    if (constant == -1) {
        VISIT(c, expr, s->v.Until.test);
        ADDOP_JABS(c, POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE, anchor);
    }
    VISIT_SEQ(c, stmt, s->v.Until.body);
    ADDOP_JABS(c, JUMP_ABSOLUTE, loop);

    if (constant == -1) {
        compiler_use_next_block(c, anchor);
        ADDOP(c, POP_BLOCK);
    }
    compiler_pop_fblock(c, LOOP, loop);
    compiler_use_next_block(c, end);

    return 1;
}
```

I have a confession to make: this code wasn't written based on a deep understanding of Python bytecode. Like the rest of the article, it was done in imitation of the kin `compiler_while` function. By reading it carefully, however, keeping in mind that the Python VM is stack-based, and glancing into the documentation of the `dis` module, which has [a list of Python bytecodes](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/dis.html) with descriptions, it's possible to understand what's going on.

#### That's it, we're done... Aren't we?

After making all the changes and running `make`, we can run the newly compiled Python and try our new `until` statement:

```
>>> until num == 0:
...   print(num)
...   num -= 1
...
3
2
1
```

Voila, it works! Let's see the bytecode created for the new statement by using the `dis` module as follows:

```
import dis

def myfoo(num):
    until num == 0:
        print(num)
        num -= 1

dis.dis(myfoo)
```

Here's the result:

```
4           0 SETUP_LOOP              36 (to 39)
      >>    3 LOAD_FAST                0 (num)
            6 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
            9 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
           12 POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE        38

5          15 LOAD_NAME                0 (print)
           18 LOAD_FAST                0 (num)
           21 CALL_FUNCTION            1
           24 POP_TOP

6          25 LOAD_FAST                0 (num)
           28 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
           31 INPLACE_SUBTRACT
           32 STORE_FAST               0 (num)
           35 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            3
      >>   38 POP_BLOCK
      >>   39 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
           42 RETURN_VALUE
```

The most interesting operation is number 12: if the condition is true, we jump to after the loop. This is correct semantics for `until`. If the jump isn't executed, the loop body keeps running until it jumps back to the condition at operation 35.

Feeling good about my change, I then tried running the function (executing `myfoo(3)`) instead of showing its bytecode. The result was less than encouraging:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "zy.py", line 9, in
    myfoo(3)
  File "zy.py", line 5, in myfoo
    print(num)
SystemError: no locals when loading 'print'
```

Whoa... this can't be good. So what went wrong?

#### The case of the missing symbol table

One of the steps the Python compiler performs when compiling the AST is create a symbol table for the code it compiles. The call to `PySymtable_Build` in `PyAST_Compile` calls into the symbol table module (`Python/symtable.c`), which walks the AST in a manner similar to the code generation functions. Having a symbol table for each scope helps the compiler figure out some key information, such as which variables are global and which are local to a scope.

To fix the problem, we have to modify the `symtable_visit_stmt` function in `Python/symtable.c`, adding code for handling `until` statements, after the similar code for `while` statements **[3]**:

```
case While_kind:
    VISIT(st, expr, s->v.While.test);
    VISIT_SEQ(st, stmt, s->v.While.body);
    if (s->v.While.orelse)
        VISIT_SEQ(st, stmt, s->v.While.orelse);
    break;
case Until_kind:
    VISIT(st, expr, s->v.Until.test);
    VISIT_SEQ(st, stmt, s->v.Until.body);
    break;
```

**[3]**: By the way, without this code there’s a compiler warning for `Python/symtable.c`. The compiler notices that the `Until_kind` enumeration value isn’t handled in the switch statement of `symtable_visit_stmt` and complains. It’s always important to check for compiler warnings!

And now we really are done. Compiling the source after this change makes the execution of `myfoo(3)` work as expected.

#### Conclusion

In this article I've demonstrated how to add a new statement to Python. Albeit requiring quite a bit of tinkering in the code of the Python compiler, the change wasn't difficult to implement, because I used a similar and existing statement as a guideline.

The Python compiler is a sophisticated chunk of software, and I don't claim being an expert in it. However, I am really interested in the internals of Python, and particularly its front-end. Therefore, I found this exercise a very useful companion to theoretical study of the compiler's principles and source code. It will serve as a base for future articles that will get deeper into the compiler.

#### References

I used a few excellent references for the construction of this article. Here they are, in no particular order:

- [PEP 339: Design of the CPython compiler](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0339/) - probably the most important and comprehensive piece of *official* documentation for the Python compiler. Being very short, it painfully displays the scarcity of good documentation of the internals of Python.
- "Python Compiler Internals" - an article by Thomas Lee
- "Python: Design and Implementation" - a presentation by Guido van Rossum
- Python (2.5) Virtual Machine, A guided tour - a presentation by Peter Tröger

[original source](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/06/30/python-internals-adding-a-new-statement-to-python/)

Comment: Excellent article(/blog), thanks! Accepting since this perfectly answers the question, and the "don't do that"/"coding: mylang" answers are already highly upvoted, so will appear nicely in order \o/

Comment: But unfortunately, this is not an answer.  The linked article is, but that you can't upvote or accept.  Answers consisting entirely of just a link are discouraged.

Comment: @Alfe: this was posted two years ago, accepted and +1'd by 16 readers. Note that it links to my own blog post, and copying a large article into StackOverflow isn't something I intend doing. Feel free to do that in a useful edit, rather than playing police.

Comment: Warning others that such an answer is not considered "good" is useful.  There is consensus about that answers being only links to sth are not "good" answers in Stackoverflow.  I won't repeat the argument here.  Anyone interested can read it at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259 (BTW, I had a very similar discussion about an answer I gave which also mainly linked another source I had written, and I got myself "missionaried".)

Comment: @EliBendersky Useful is quite an understatement for that article. Thanks for explaining so much about how these things actually work in python. This has really helped me understand the AST, which is relevant to my current work. **also, in case you're curious, my version of `until` is `isa`/`isan` as in `if something isa dict:` or `if something isan int:`

Comment: Soo, this answer is "Write and compile your own language from source, forked from python"

Comment: Has anyone done a kind of more involved sophisticated work - not just a piggy-back on existing form?

Example - to add label: <name> and extend break to break: <name> (yes Javaism :-). That "April's joke" doesn't count since that was a kind of pre-processing and either doesn't work in interactive mode of it broken outside of 2.7 word.

BTW I come for the Forth side of the universe as well and I miss the ability to extend the language with "unbearable ease" :-) a lot. Python looks like it should have all predispositions to become capable of handling extensions with ease.

Answer (score 59):

One way to do things like this is to preprocess the source and modify it, translating your added statement to python.  There are various problems this approach will bring, and I wouldn't recommend it for general usage, but for experimentation with language, or specific-purpose metaprogramming, it can occassionally be useful.

For instance, lets say we want to introduce a "myprint" statement, that instead of printing to the screen instead logs to a specific file.  ie:

```
myprint "This gets logged to file"
```

would be equivalent to

```
print >>open('/tmp/logfile.txt','a'), "This gets logged to file"
```

There are various options as to how to do the replacing, from regex substitution to generating an AST, to writing your own parser depending on how close your syntax matches existing python.  A good intermediate approach is to use the tokenizer module.  This should allow you to add new keywords, control structures etc while interpreting the source similarly to the python interpreter, thus avoiding the breakage crude regex solutions would cause.  For the above "myprint", you could write the following transformation code:

```
import tokenize

LOGFILE = '/tmp/log.txt'
def translate(readline):
    for type, name,_,_,_ in tokenize.generate_tokens(readline):
        if type ==tokenize.NAME and name =='myprint':
            yield tokenize.NAME, 'print'
            yield tokenize.OP, '>>'
            yield tokenize.NAME, "open"
            yield tokenize.OP, "("
            yield tokenize.STRING, repr(LOGFILE)
            yield tokenize.OP, ","
            yield tokenize.STRING, "'a'"
            yield tokenize.OP, ")"
            yield tokenize.OP, ","
        else:
            yield type,name
```

(This does make myprint effectively a keyword, so use as a variable elsewhere will likely cause problems)

The problem then is how to use it so that your code is usable from python.  One way would just be to write your own import function, and use it to load code written in your custom language.  ie:

```
import new
def myimport(filename):
    mod = new.module(filename)
    f=open(filename)
    data = tokenize.untokenize(translate(f.readline))
    exec data in mod.__dict__
    return mod
```

This requires you handle your customised code differently from normal python modules however.  ie "`some_mod = myimport("some_mod.py")`" rather than "`import some_mod`"

Another fairly neat (albeit hacky) solution is to create a custom encoding (See [PEP 263](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/)) as [this](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/546539/) recipe demonstrates.  You could implement this as:

```
import codecs, cStringIO, encodings
from encodings import utf_8

class StreamReader(utf_8.StreamReader):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        codecs.StreamReader.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        data = tokenize.untokenize(translate(self.stream.readline))
        self.stream = cStringIO.StringIO(data)

def search_function(s):
    if s!='mylang': return None
    utf8=encodings.search_function('utf8') # Assume utf8 encoding
    return codecs.CodecInfo(
        name='mylang',
        encode = utf8.encode,
        decode = utf8.decode,
        incrementalencoder=utf8.incrementalencoder,
        incrementaldecoder=utf8.incrementaldecoder,
        streamreader=StreamReader,
        streamwriter=utf8.streamwriter)

codecs.register(search_function)
```

Now after this code gets run (eg. you could place it in your .pythonrc or site.py) any code starting with the comment "# coding: mylang" will automatically be translated through the above preprocessing step.  eg.

```
# coding: mylang
myprint "this gets logged to file"
for i in range(10):
    myprint "so does this : ", i, "times"
myprint ("works fine" "with arbitrary" + " syntax" 
  "and line continuations")
```

Caveats:

There are problems to the preprocessor approach, as you'll probably be familiar with if you've worked with the C preprocessor.  The main one is debugging.  All python sees is the preprocessed file which means that text printed in the stack trace etc will refer to that.  If you've performed significant translation, this may be very different from your source text.  The example above doesn't change line numbers etc, so won't be too different, but the more you change it, the harder it will be to figure out.

Comment: Nice one! Instead of saying 'can't be dun' you actually give a few good answers (that boils down to 'you really don't want to do this') Upvote.

Comment: I am not sure I understand how the first example works - trying to use `myimport` on a module that simply contains `print 1` as it's only line of code yields `=1 ... SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: @noam: not sure what's failing for you - here I just get "1" printed as expected.  (This is with the 2 blocks starting "import tokenize" and "import new" above put in file a.py, as well as "`b=myimport("b.py")`", and b.py containing just "`print 1`".  Is there anything more to the error (stack trace etc)?

Comment: Python3 doesn't seem to allow this, though not necessarily on purpose; I get a BOM error.

Comment: note that `import` uses the builtin `__import__`, so if you overwrite that (_before_ importing the module that requires the modified import), you don't need a separate `myimport`

Comment: shouldn't `codecs.StreamReader.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)` be `super(StreamReader, self).__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)`?

Answer (score 22):

Yes, to some extent it is possible. There is a [module](http://entrian.com/goto/) out there that uses `sys.settrace()` to implement `goto` and `comefrom` "keywords":

```
from goto import goto, label
for i in range(1, 10):
  for j in range(1, 20):
    print i, j
    if j == 3:
      goto .end # breaking out from nested loop
label .end
print "Finished"
```

Comment: That's not really new syntax though... it just looks like it.

Comment: -1: The linked page has this heading: "The 'goto' module was an April Fool's joke, published on 1st April 2004. Yes, it works, but it's a joke nevertheless. Please don't use it in real code!"

Comment: @Jim might reconsider a -1. it hints you on the implementation mechanism. nice thing to start with.

Answer (score 14):

Short of changing and recompiling the source code (which *is* possible with open source), changing the base language is not really possible.

Even if you do recompile the source, it wouldn't be python, just your hacked-up changed version which you need to be very careful not to introduce bugs into.

However, I'm not sure why you'd want to.  Python's object-oriented features makes it quite simple to achieve similar results with the language as it stands.

Comment: I disagree on one point.  If you *add* new keywords I think it would still be Python.  If you *change* existing keywords, then that's just hacked-up, as you say.

Comment: If you add new keywords, it would be a Python-derived language. If you change keywords, it would be a Python-incompatible language.

Comment: If you add keywords, you might be missing the point of "simple easy-to-learn syntax" and "extensive libraries".  I think language features are almost always a mistake (examples include COBOL, Perl and PHP).

Comment: New keywords would break Python code which uses them as identifiers.

Answer (score 13):

General answer: you need to preprocess your source files.

More specific answer: install [EasyExtend](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/EasyExtend), and go through following steps

i) Create a new langlet ( extension language )

```
import EasyExtend
EasyExtend.new_langlet("mystmts", prompt = "my> ", source_ext = "mypy")
```

Without additional specification a bunch of files shall be created under EasyExtend/langlets/mystmts/ .

ii) Open mystmts/parsedef/Grammar.ext and add following lines

```
small_stmt: (expr_stmt | print_stmt  | del_stmt | pass_stmt | flow_stmt |
             import_stmt | global_stmt | exec_stmt | assert_stmt | my_stmt )

my_stmt: 'mystatement' expr
```

This is sufficient to define the syntax of your new statement. The small_stmt non-terminal is part of the Python grammar and it's the place where the new statement is hooked in. The parser will now recognize the new statement i.e. a source file containing it will be parsed. The compiler will reject it though because it still has to be transformed into valid Python.

iii) Now one has to add semantics of the statement. For this one has to edit
 msytmts/langlet.py and add a my_stmt node visitor.

```
 def call_my_stmt(expression):
     "defines behaviour for my_stmt"
     print "my stmt called with", expression

 class LangletTransformer(Transformer):
       @transform
       def my_stmt(self, node):
           _expr = find_node(node, symbol.expr)
           return any_stmt(CST_CallFunc("call_my_stmt", [_expr]))

 __publish__ = ["call_my_stmt"]
```

iv) cd to langlets/mystmts and type

```
python run_mystmts.py
```

Now a session shall be started and the newly defined statement can be used:

```
__________________________________________________________________________________

 mystmts

 On Python 2.5.1 (r251:54863, Apr 18 2007, 08:51:08) [MSC v.1310 32 bit (Intel)]
 __________________________________________________________________________________

 my> mystatement 40+2
 my stmt called with 42
```

Quite a few steps to come to a trivial statement, right? There isn't an API yet that lets one define simple things without having to care about grammars. But EE is very reliable modulo some bugs. So it's just a matter of time that an API emerges that lets programmers define convenient stuff like infix operators or small statements using just convenient OO programming. For more complex things like embedding whole languages in Python by means of building a langlet there is no way of going around a full grammar approach.

Answer (score 12):

Here's a very simple but crappy way to add new statements, *in interpretive mode only*. I'm using it for little 1-letter commands for editing gene annotations using only sys.displayhook, but just so I could answer this question I added sys.excepthook for the syntax errors as well. The latter is really ugly, fetching the raw code from the readline buffer. The benefit is, it's trivially easy to add new statements this way.

```
jcomeau@intrepid:~/$ cat demo.py; ./demo.py
#!/usr/bin/python -i
'load everything needed under "package", such as package.common.normalize()'
import os, sys, readline, traceback
if __name__ == '__main__':
    class t:
        @staticmethod
        def localfunction(*args):
            print 'this is a test'
            if args:
                print 'ignoring %s' % repr(args)

    def displayhook(whatever):
        if hasattr(whatever, 'localfunction'):
            return whatever.localfunction()
        else:
            print whatever

    def excepthook(exctype, value, tb):
        if exctype is SyntaxError:
            index = readline.get_current_history_length()
            item = readline.get_history_item(index)
            command = item.split()
            print 'command:', command
            if len(command[0]) == 1:
                try:
                    eval(command[0]).localfunction(*command[1:])
                except:
                    traceback.print_exception(exctype, value, tb)
        else:
            traceback.print_exception(exctype, value, tb)

    sys.displayhook = displayhook
    sys.excepthook = excepthook
>>> t
this is a test
>>> t t
command: ['t', 't']
this is a test
ignoring ('t',)
>>> ^D
```

Answer (score 4):

I've found a guide on adding new statements:

https://troeger.eu/files/teaching/pythonvm08lab.pdf

Basically, to add new statements, you must edit `Python/ast.c` (among other things) and recompile the python binary.

While it's possible, don't. You can achieve almost everything via functions and classes (which wont require people to recompile python just to run your script..)

Comment: The real link to PDF - that "autonversion" is broken and has been broken for God know s now long:

https://troeger.eu/files/teaching/pythonvm08lab.pdf

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to do this using [EasyExtend](http://www.fiber-space.de/EasyExtend/doc/EE.html):

> EasyExtend (EE) is a preprocessor
>   generator and metaprogramming
>   framework written in pure Python and
>   integrated with CPython. The main
>   purpose of EasyExtend is the creation
>   of extension languages i.e. adding
>   custom syntax and semantics to Python.

Comment: Following that link now gives a page: "EasyExtend is dead. For those who are interested in EE there is
            a successor project called

                              Langscape

            Different name, complete redesign, same journey." Since there's the danger that this information page may go dead, maybe it's a good idea to update the answer.

Answer (score 3):

It's not exactly adding new statements to the language syntax, but macros are a powerful tool: https://github.com/lihaoyi/macropy

Answer (score 2):

**OUTDATED**:
The Logix project is now deprecated and no longer developed, per [the Logix website](http://logix-language.sourceforge.net/).

There is a language based on python called [Logix](http://www.livelogix.net/logix/) with which you CAN do such things.  It hasn't been under development for a while, but the features that you asked for **do work** with the latest version.

Comment: Sounds interesting, but seems to have died around 2009: https://web.archive.org/web/20090107014050/http://livelogix.net/logix/

Answer (score 2):

Some things can be done with decorators. Let's e.g. assume, Python had no `with` statement. We could then implement a similar behaviour like this:

```
# ====== Implementation of "mywith" decorator ======

def mywith(stream):
    def decorator(function):
        try: function(stream)
        finally: stream.close()
    return decorator

# ====== Using the decorator ======

@mywith(open("test.py","r"))
def _(infile):
    for l in infile.readlines():
        print(">>", l.rstrip())
```

It is a pretty unclean solution however as done here. Especially the behaviour where the decorator calls the function and sets `_` to `None` is unexpected. For clarification: This decorator is equivalent to writing

```
def _(infile): ...
_ = mywith(open(...))(_) # mywith returns None.
```

and decorators are normally expected to modify, not to execute, functions.

I used such a method before in a script where I had to temporarily set the working directory for several functions.

Answer (score 1):

Not without modifying the interpreter.  I know a lot of languages in the past several years have been described as "extensible", but not in the way you're describing.  You extend Python by adding functions and classes.

Answer (score 0):

Ten years ago you couldn't, and I doubt that's changed.  However, it wasn't that hard to modify the syntax back then if you were prepared to recompile python, and I doubt that's changed, either.