# Possible to call single-parameter Python function without using parentheses?

Tags: python, syntax

The Python documentation specifies that is is legal to omit the parentheses if a function only takes a single parameter, but

```
myfunction "Hello!"
```

generates a syntax error.  So, what's the deal?

EDIT:

The statement that I read only applies to [*generator expressions*](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions):

> The parentheses can be omitted on calls with only one argument.

Comment: Are you sure? Can you tell us where do you read that rule? Are you confusing with ruby?

Comment: You are probably confusing Python with Ruby or Lua, where parantheses can be omitted sometimes.

Comment: @Jen: they talk about parentheses that denote generator, not the function call.

Comment: It is confusing for beginners that some Python words are statements and others are functions, especially as they're moving them around between versions.

Comment: The IPython (http://ipython.scipy.org/moin/) interactive interpreter can omit parentheses, but the `python` interpreter only allows this for keywords (http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For your edit:

If you write down a generator expression, like `stuff = (f(x) for x in items)` you need the brackets, just like you need the `[ .. ]` around a list comprehension.

But when you pass something from a generator expression to a function (which is a pretty common pattern, because that's pretty much the big idea behind generators) then you don't need two sets of brackets - instead of something like `s = sum((f(x) for x in items))` (outer brackets to indicate a function call, inner for the generator expression) you can just write `sum(f(x) for x in items)`

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with IPython -- the [`%autocall` magic command](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-autocall) controls this feature (as well as the `-autocall` command line option). Use `%autocall 0` to disable the feature, `%autocall 1`, the default, to have it work only when an argument is present, and `%autocall 2` to have it work even for argument-less callables.

```
In [2]: %autocall 1
Automatic calling is: Smart

In [3]: int '5'
------> int('5')
Out[3]: 5

In [4]: %autocall 2
Automatic calling is: Full

In [5]: int
------> int()
Out[5]: 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Without parentheses those wouldn't be `functions` but `statements` or `keywords` (language-intrinsic).

[This StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214881/can-you-add-new-statements-to-pythons-syntax) (with some very nice answers) [contains a lead as](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214881/can-you-add-new-statements-to-pythons-syntax/216795#216795) to how one can create their own in pure Python (through advanced hackery, and not a good idea in 99.99% of the cases).

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the rule is only about the generator expressions...
so for example:

```
sum(x**2 for x in range(10))
```

but you would still have to write:

```
reduce(operator.add, (x**2 for x in range(10)))
```

This doesn't apply for generic functions though.