# Is there a possibility to override a unary operator with a binary one in Python?

Tags: python, operator-overloading, unary-operator

I tried to define a class and override the tilde operator:

```
class foo:
    def __invert__(self, other)
        return 1232 # a random number , just as test
```

Then calling it like:

```
>>> f = foo()
>>> g = foo()
>>> f ~ g
  File "<input>", line 1
    f ~ g
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can we replace the tilde operator  with a binary one so we can do  an operation like `f ~ g` without raising a syntax error.

Comment: Not without modifying Python itself, no (although you can do so if you wish - see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214881/can-you-add-new-statements-to-pythons-syntax for an introduction).

Comment: @jonrsharpe: and even then, how would the number of operands by altered *at runtime*? Your only option would be to change the `~` operator meaning completely, you can't choose between 1 or 2 operands at runtime.

Comment: @MartijnPieters that is true, you would lose the unary version

Comment: Why would you? There's a unary and a binary `+`. The choice is made at parse time. Of course you need different `__names__` for it.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I just heard a claim that the R's tilde operator (binary) is brought up to Python.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, you can't do that, not without radically altering how Python compiles bytecode. All expressions are first *parsed* into a Abstract Syntax Tree, then compiled into bytecode from that, and it is at the parsing stage that operands and operators are grouped.

By the time the bytecode runs you can no longer decide to accept two operands.