# Is it possible to create string decorators?

Tags: python-2.7

In Python I can automatically create an unicode object by prepending an `u` (as in `u"test"`).

Is it possible to build something like that myself?

Comment: That is not possible, the special treatment of string prefixes is hardcoded in the language implementation.

Comment: `r'...'` is a regular string, just without backslash interpolation, etc. It is commonly used for strings which contain regular expressions, among other things, but it's still just a string.

Comment: @triplee: thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All things are possible - but in this case, only by modifying the source code of the Python interpreter and recompiling.

A related question with the same answer:  [Can you add new statements to Python's syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214881/can-you-add-new-statements-to-pythons-syntax)

Comment: I see, thanks for that answer! Kinda disappointing since python usually allows me to change pretty much everything else.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

All you need to do is type the following:

```
ur"\u<hex>"
```

For example, if you were to type

```
print ur"\u0186"
```

it would output the following character (given you are using a certain font)

҉

To print this, you could just simply type

```
print "҉"
```

but for this to be allowed, you must put the following line of code as the FIRST line of code

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Yes, I know it has the # symbol, that is supposed to be there.
Hope this helps!  Have fun with unicoding!  :)

Comment: Useful info for working with unicode in Python, but I don't think that's what the OP is asking.  I think the question is, "can I make my own novel type of string literal, let's say `m'...'`, with custom-defined rules and behaviour?"

Comment: It is useful info indeed, but as jez pointed out, it's not what I was asking for. jez had the right interpretation of my post. Thanks for the answer anyways though!