# Is it possible to define my own function sign like '==' or '+string'?

Tags: python, class, syntax, function

Is it possible do define your own function which can be used as a non-alphabetic function sign?

I'm just curious whether it is possible.

I don't want to change some existing function like `__eq__` or `__gt__`.

For example '***' sign would do this computation on `Int`: `x***x = x^2^2`. So I would define this function and then I could use it this way:

```
for x in xrange(3):
    print x***x

- 0
- 1
- 16
- 81
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/214881/3001761

Comment: Any valid identifier can be an infix operator with [this clever hack](http://tomerfiliba.com/blog/Infix-Operators/) - however, IIRC, `***` is not a valid identifier name, so some of the more esoteric operators cannot be created.  No `<<+|` - both fortunately and unfortunately.

Comment: This might be helpful to know which identifiers are allowed: https://docs.python.org/3.2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers. In Python 2, however, only alphabetical characters, numbers, and underscores are allowed.