# Should you use the underscore _ as an "access modifier indicator" in non-library code in Python?

Tags: python, semantics

## Introduction

---

So I've been doing a bit of research regarding the underscore character (`_`). I know most of its use cases and its semantics in them so I'll just drop them below as a recap and I'll conclude with the question, which is more of a conceptual one regarding 2 of the use cases.

## Use cases

---

1. To store the last evaluation in an interpreter (outside the interpreter it [has no special semantics](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#reserved-classes-of-identifiers) and it's undefined as a single character)
2. [In internationalization context](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#reserved-classes-of-identifiers), where you'd import functions such as `gettext` aliased as `_`
3. In decimal grouping to aid visibility (specifically doing groups of 3 such as 1_000_000) - *Note that this is only available from Python 3.6 onward*.

   Example:

   ```
   1_000_000 == 10**6  # equals True
   x = 1_000
   print(x)  # yields 1000
   ```
4. To "ignore" certain values, although I'd not call it "ignore" since those values are still evaluated and bound to `_` just as though it were a regular identifier. Normally I'd find a better design than this since I find this a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell). I have rarely used such an approach in many years so I guess whenever you think you need to use it, you can surely improve your design to not use it.

   Example:

   ```
   for _ in range(10):
       # do stuff without _
       ping_a_server()

   # outside loop that still exists and it still has the last evaluated value
   print(_)  # would yield 9
   ```
5. Trailing an identifier ([used by convention](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles) to avoid name clashes with a built-in identifier or reserved word):

   Example

   ```
   class Automobile:

       def __init__(self, type_='luxury', class_='executive'):
           self.car_type = type_
           self.car_class = class_

   noob_car = Automobile(type_='regular', class_='supermini')
   luxury = Automobile()
   ```
6. As access modifiers [but only as a convetion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics#Objects) since Python doesn't have [access modifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_modifiers) in the true sense:

   **Single leading underscore**

   ---

   [Acts as a weak "internal use" indicator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles). All identifiers starting with `_` will be ignored by star imports (`from M import *`)

   Example:

   ```
   a.py

   _bogus = "I'm a bogus variable"
   __bogus = "I'm a bogus with 2 underscores"
   ___triple = 3.1415
   class_ = 'Plants'
   type_ = 'Red'
   regular_identifier = (x for x in range(10))

   b.py
   from a import *
   print(locals())  # will yield all but the ones starting with _
   ```

   **Important conceptual observation**

   **I hate it when people call this private (excluding the fact that 
   nothing's actually private in Python)**.
   If we were to put this in an analogy this would be equivalent to [Java's protected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_modifiers#Names_of_keywords), since in Java protected means "*derived classes and/or within same package*". So since at the module level any identifier with a leading underscore `_` has a different semantics than a regular identifier (and I'm talking about semantics from Python's perspective not our perspective where `CONSTANTS` and `global_variable` mean different things but to Python they're the same thing) and is ignored by the import machinery when talking about start imports, this really is an indicator that you should use those identifiers within that module or within the classes they're defined in or their derived subclasses.

   **Double leading underscores**

   ---

   Without going into much details, this invokes a name mangling mechanism
   when used on identifiers inside a class, which makes it harder, but 
   again, not impossible for folks to access an attribute from classes that 
   subclass that base class.

## Question

---

So I've been reading [this book](http://do1.dr-chuck.com/pythonlearn/EN_us/pythonlearn.pdf) dedicated to beginners and at the variables section the author said something like:

> Variables can begin with an underscore _ although we generally avoid doing this unless we write library code for others to use.

Which got me thinking... **does it make sense to mark stuff as non-public in a private project or even in an open source project that's not used as a dependency in other projects?**

For instance, I have an **[open source web app](https://github.com/mariusmucenicu/knowlift)**, that I push changes to on a regular basis. Its mostly there for educational purposes and because I want to write clean, standardized code and put in practice any new skills I acquire along the way. Now I'm thinking of the aformentioned: **does it make sense to use identifiers that mark things non-public?**

For the sake of argument let us say that in the future 500 people are actively contributing to that web app and it becomes very active code-wise. We can assume a large number of folks will use those "protected" and "private" identifiers directly (even when that's advised against, not all 500 of them would know the best practices) but **since it's a non-library project**, meaning it's not a dependency in other projects or that other people use, they can be "somewhat" reassured in a sense that those methods won't disappear in a code refactor, as the developer doing the refactor is likely going to notice all callers across the project and will refactor accordingly (or he won't notice but tests will tell him).

Evidently it makes sense in a library code, since all the people depending on your library and all the possible future people depending on your library or people that indirectly are dependant on your library (other folks embed your library into theirs and expose their library and so on) should be aware that identifiers that have a **single trailing underscore** or **double trailing underscores** are an implementation detail and can change at anytime. Therefore they should use your public API at all times.

What if no people will work on this project and I'll make it private and I'll be the only one working on it? Or a small subset of people. **Does it make sense to use access modifier indicators in these kind of projects?**

Comment: i think you're overcomplicating things, if you want to indicate that something is intended to be private, you can use a leading `_` by convention, but it doesn't guarantee anything or impact the way the object can be used

Comment: @Chris_Rands I'm sry but this doesn't even remotely answer my question. I already know and covered what you've said. Also do note that `_` is rather analogous to  **protected** rather than **private** in terms of access modifier semantics. I've also covered that in the description. The question is about something else, it's about whether you should use this indicator in private or non-library code and why.

Comment: I don't see why you would treat library and non-library code different in this respect, it feels like an artificial distinction also IMO

Comment: This is a matter of subjective opinion. The core of which is: do you view code in one module of your project as an API for the rest of the project to use, or not?

Comment: @MartijnPieters fair enough! but the information in the accepted answer is valuable to me (and probably others). Will this question be auto-deleted by the system in a given time frame if it's marked as opinion-based or closed?

Comment: @George As long as a question has an answer that is either accepted or has positive score, that question will not be automatically deleted. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba for the exact conditions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your point of view seems to be based on the assumption that what is private or public ( or the equivalent suggestions in python ) is based on the developer who read and write code. That is wrong.

Even if you write all alone a single application that you only will use, if it is correctly designed it will be divided into modules, and those modules will expose an interface and have a private implementation.

The fact that you write both the module and the code that uses it doesn't mean that there are not parts which should be private to keep encapsulation. So yes, having the leading underscore to mark parts of a module as private make sense regardless of the number of developer working on the project or depending by it.

**EDIT**:

What we are really discussing about is [**encapsulation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)), which is the concept, general to software engineering for python and any other language.

The idea is that you divide your whole application into pieces (the modules I was talking about, which might be python packages but might also be something else in your design) and decide which of the several functionality needed to perform your goal is implemented there (this is called the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)).

It is a good approach to [design by contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract), which means to decide the abstraction your module is going to expose to other parts of the software and to hide everything which is not part of it as an implementation detail. Other modules should not rely on your implementation by only on your exposed functionalities so that you are free to change whenever you want to increase performance, favor new functionalities, improve maintainability or any other reason.

Now, all this theoretical rant is language agnostic and application agnostic, which means that every time you design a piece of software you have to rely on the facilities offered by the language to design your modules and to build encapsulation.

Python, one of the few if not the only one, as far as I know, has made the deliberate choice (bad, in my opinion), to not enforce encapsulation but to allow developers to have access to everything, as you have already discovered.

This, however, does not mean that the aforementioned concepts do not apply, but just that they cannot be enforced at the language level and must be implemented in a more loose way, as a simple suggestion.

Does it mean it is a bad idea to encapsulate implementation and freely use each bit of information available? Obviously not, it is still a good [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) principle upon which build an architecture.

Nothing of all this is really necessary, they are just good principles that with time and experience have been proven to create good quality software.

*Should you use in your small application that nobody else uses it?* If you want things done as they should be, yes, you should.

*Are they necessary?* Well, you can make it work without, but you might discover that it will cost you more effort later down the way.

*What if I'm not writing a library but a finished application?* Well, does that mean that you shouldn't write it in a good, clean, tidy way?

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced and here's why: The interface you're referring to is defined via the `__all__` attribute, which lists the module's **PUBLIC API**, however that attribute is useful only for modules that are _designed_ to be used via `from M import *`. If I simply import the module, I'll have access to any of it's variables regarding of whether they're marked as public or protected and there's nothing stopping me from accessing them through the module's namespace. So yes, what is private and public **is** based on the developer since they're all the same for python in a regular import

Comment: There's no barrier between the object and the developer and this is even emphasized by the slogan "We're all responsible users here". So if a developer sees an identifier (method, attribute, etc) with a leading `_` he should know that he shouldn't use that identifier as it might change over time. But, as I've mentioned this applies to external **library code**, over which you have no control. E.g if you use `_x` and you upgrade the version and `_x` is gone your app will crash. And you should've expected this as `_x` was an implementation detail and shouldn't have been used directly.

Comment: So yeah, what is **public** and **private** is entirely up to the developer since it's not enforced. It's totally based on conventions and following those conventions, except for the special case mentioned above (the `from M import *` case). Going back to my question, in a private project the principle still holds, but is it necessary? Using `_identifier` directly can be somewhat safe since at a code refactor both the declaration and all the callers should be modified.

Comment: I edited the answer to better clear my point. Also, as an added point, the fact that python does not enforce visibility doesn't mean that it should not follow the same principle. I mean, what's the difference between making every property as "suggested" public or making a Java class completely public?

Comment: Amazing edit, accepted! Thanks for the insights!