# Python parse csv element called "class" (Python keyword)

Tags: python, csv, parsing

i am new to python, trying to parse a csv. Made some bounding boxes for MNIST. Now i want to convert the csv to xmls to train a yolo detector.

But i came along a pretty strange thing: (python keywords^^)

These are my rows, got thousends of them, 10 to one image:

```
filename    mnist_images_300_300_bigger_all/mnist_1.jpg
width                                               300
height                                              300
class                                                 7
xmin                                                  0
ymin                                                  0
xmax                                                 42
ymax                                                 42
Name: 0, dtype: object
Path were to write xml:  Bilder_LabelXML/mnist_images_300_300_bigger_all/mnist_1.xml
Path were image from:    mnist_images_300_300_bigger_all/mnist_1.jpg
```

If i want to access them now, i wrote in my script:

```
for index, row in group.object.iterrows():
    print(row.class)
```

Which gave me that error:

```
File "annotations_CSV_to_XML.py", line 81
    ET.SubElement(size, "name").text = row.class
                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If i access ymax, everything is fine:

```
for index, row in group.object.iterrows():
    print(row.ymin)
```

How can i delimit or mask the keyword "class", that python understands it and does not thing i want to create a new class?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/44859431/476

Comment: solved it by using row[3] instead of row.class

Comment: Or consider row['class'].

Comment: okay thought i had tried it, but obviously not, it works with row['class']... thx alot