# Create Object With Attribute Named Global

Tags: python, python-3.x

For business logic reasons I want to be able to create an object that has an attribute named `global`. But I obviously can't just do

```
class Foo(object):
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.global = True
```

Because `global` is a reserved keyword that has special meaning in Python. Dynamically getting the attribute using `__getattr__` or `__getattribute__` has the same problem though. Is there anyway that I can do this, or do I have to make the attribute name `global_`?

I need to be able to access the attribute directly from the object, so I can't use `getattr(foo, 'global')`.

Comment: No, unfortunately I need to be able to access the attribute directly on the object.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to do  global_, I don't think there's any way to bypass this, since naming with reserved keywords is illegal and creates all sorts of issues.

Edit:
You can check out this post though: [How to use reserved keyword as the name of variable in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44859431/how-to-use-reserved-keyword-as-the-name-of-variable-in-python)

Comment: As pointed out by the link, it's only illegal syntactically. You can create an attribute by that name with `setattr(self, 'global', True)`, but for the same syntactic reasons you'd have to access it with `getattr(self, 'global')`.

Comment: Also, note this limitation is due to the old Python parser. While the new PEG-based parser *could* allow `self.global = True` to be valid, I don't know if there are any plans to make it so. (Basically, the new grammar allows keywords to be reserved based on context. This is how the new `match` keyword is being added without invalidating code that uses `match` as an identifier.)