# Is it possible to overload keywords in Python?

Tags: python, keyword

Is it possible to overload the meaning of different keywords in Python? I'd like to implement my own version of `if` and `for` etc.

Comment: No. God no. Please, no.

Comment: You can implement custom behavior of objects in response to most operators though, including *truthiness* and iteration behavior. So why modify keywords?

Comment: Sounds like you'd like to write your own language.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214881/can-you-add-new-statements-to-pythons-syntax

Comment: While everyone else is busy saying no, I'll take the opportunity to ask: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Sounds like you're making [bobx](https://thedailywtf.com/articles/We-Use-BobX)

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible in any way*. You can only overload the behavior of [operators](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names), such as `+`, `==`, and `[]`.

<sup><sup>Without recompiling your own fork of Python, and thus essentially making a new language.</sup></sup>