# Creating a Python keyword equal to another

Tags: python, keyword

I am interested in wondering if I can create another keyword equal to another. I'm not sure if it is possible, but I have an idea: let's say I want to create a keyword in a different language equal to an existing Python keyword, like this:

```
new_keyword = if
```

Is that possible in Python?

Comment: Possible at what level? You could patch the interpreter, but you can't do this *in Python itself* (err, unless you're using PyPy, I guess). What do you mean *"in a different language"*?

Comment: Not a *keyword*. You can mess around with most other things, though.

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/214881/3001761

Comment: You cannot bind a name to a statement. This looks like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to solve?